# VBA reading cell values into a list then using it

Tags: vba, list

I have a long list of data, one line for one movement. I need to check the volumes of the movements by location. The locations can be grouped, as some of them has the same criteria for filtering. For doing that I would like to read the cell values into a list and then looping through the original list of data by checking into which group does the location belongs. I don't know how to read the group into a list in a way that then I can check if a cell value matches with any of the items in the original - to be filtered - list.
Can anyone help with it? Also, in case you have any other suggestion for the solution, I appreciate it too.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us your own solution or at least a attempts to present your effort. Without any data or code to analyze I can suggest sth like this:

```
Sub Make_a_List()
Dim TableWithData() as Variant

TableWithData = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(100,100)) 'Values as example

End Sub
```

This gives you an table with elements of the specified range. For one row you will get one dimension table.

Then for instance you can make a for loop:

```
For i=1 to Ubound(TableWithData)
     if TableWithData(i) = sth then
        do whatever you need
     end if
Next i
```